# Unable to find to find touchopad in DConf Editor

Tags: touchpad

I'm trying to reverse the finger scroll, on my Ubuntu laptop, so I've install DConf Editor but I don't have the option of touchpad .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shall look in `dconf-editor` at following path:
`/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad` `natural-scroll`?

[image]

Or you can try the settings:
`/Settings/Mouse & Touchpad` `Natural Scrolling`
[image]